# Vector push_back: doesn't convert parameter

Tags: c++

Well, what I'm trying to do is to push back an object of the class I called `Block` onto different vectors that keep `Block` elements and are saved in a vector themselves.

```
std::vector<std::vector<Block>> mapvec;
mapvec[xcnt].push_back(new Block(xcnt,ycnt));
```

This is my progress until now.

```
error C2664: 'std::vector<_Ty>::push_back': convetion of the parameter 'Block *' in 'const Block &' not possible
```

(translated from German)

What should I do? Is there any other way to do what I want? Without using arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new` returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated object. This is not what you want to do here. Usually you want to pass a temporary (or already existing) object to `push_back` and it will insert a copy into the memory.

So, simply get rid of `new`. Like so:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Block>> mapvec;
mapvec[xcnt].push_back(Block(xcnt,ycnt));
```

This will make a temporary `Block`-object and insert a copy into the vector.

If you want to use `new` you need to store pointers in the vector, not `Block`-objects. The safest way to do this is to use smart pointers:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Block>>> mapvec;
mapvec[xcnt].push_back(std::unique_ptr<Block>(new Block(xcnt, ycnt)));
```

That way, the memory allocated with `new` will be freed using `delete` as soon as you remove the item from the vector or the vector gets destroyed.

Comment: Ok thanks to you guys, that worked out well! Do you think it's okay to ask question which are so easy to answer on stackoverflow ^^

Comment: It's ok in general, but you will find similar questions which have already been answered multiple times. Please make use of the search function and do not post duplicates of other questions. Just show that you tried to find an answer yourself before asking the community for help.

Comment: Oh and if one of the answers helped you solve your problem please mark it as the answer (doesn't necessarily have to be mine).

Answer (score 1):

Define your `mapvec` as

```
std::vector<std::vector<Block*>> mapvec;
```

instead?

Comment: @Excelcius Taking into account how the question was asked, this is maybe not the most safe solution but it answers how to fix the compiler complaint. And I do agree that you supply the better solution in your answer.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is wrong but it looks like a beginner-question to me so he probably doesn't know that he has to call delete for every item in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
new Block(xcnt,ycnt)
```

gives you `Block*` pointing to the newly allocated `Block`. And your vector expects `Block` not `Block*`

---

Change it to

```
mapvec[xcnt].push_back(Block(xcnt,ycnt));
```

This will copy your `Block` in to the vector so `Block` class should have an accessible copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should :

```
mapvec[xcnt].push_back(Block(xcnt,ycnt));
```

Because you are holding instances of Block's, not their pointers